# How to modify string to char array in C/C++?

Tags: c++

i'm writing a program called 'Zuma'. The program works like this.

```
Input:
    ACCBA // a string make up of char from 'A' to 'Z'
    5     // number of inputs
    1 B   // insert char 'B' to position '1' of the string
    0 A   // and so on...
    2 B
    4 C
    0 A
```

When 3 same chars next to each other, we erase/remove/delete them from the string.

For example, when we insert char 'C' to position 2 of string 'ABCC', we got 'AB' because
'CCC' are removed from the string.

```
Output:
    ABCCBA
    AABCCBA
    AABBCCBA  // the process is AABBCCCBA -> AABBBA -> AAA -> -
    -         // if the string is empty, we output "-"
    A
```

This is my code with string:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, pos;
    int k = 0;
    int length = 0;

    string zuma, marble; // i use string

    cin >> zuma;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> pos >> marble;
        zuma.insert(pos, marble);

        length = zuma.length();       // length of current string

        // compare each char from pos[i] with pos[i+1] and pos[i+2]
        // and then ++i until end of string
        while (k != length && length >= 3)
        {
            if (zuma[k] == zuma[k + 1] && zuma[k] == zuma[k + 2])
            {
                zuma.erase(k, 3);     // erase 3 same char in the string
                k = 0;                // set k to zero to start from pos[0] again
            }
            else
                k++;
        }

        // if string is not empty
        if (!zuma.empty())
        {
            cout << zuma << endl;     // output the current char in the string
            k = 0;
        }
        else
            cout << "-" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my code with char array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void append (char subject[], const char insert[], int pos) {
    char buf[100] = {}; 
    strncpy(buf, subject, pos); 
    int len = strlen(buf);
    strcpy(buf+len, insert);
    len += strlen(insert);

    strcpy(buf+len, subject+pos);

    strcpy(subject, buf);

}

int main()
{
    int n, pos;
    int k = 0;
    int length = 0;

    char zuma[100], marble[100];

    scanf("%s", zuma);
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d %s", &pos, marble);

        append(zuma, marble, pos); // acts like string::insert

        length = strlen(zuma);

        while (k != length && length >= 3)
        {
            if (zuma[k] == zuma[k + 1] && zuma[k] == zuma[k + 2])
            {
                //zuma.erase(k, 3);     // need help with this part to remove 3 same chars like string::erase
                k = 0;
            }
            else
                k++;
        }

        if (strlen(zuma) != 0)
        {
            printf("%s\n", zuma);
            k = 0;
        }
        else
            printf("%s\n","-");

     }

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is how to write a function to remove 3 same chars just like what string::erase do?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: To clarify: You want to do with char arrays what you can already do with strings in a clearer, safer and more concise way? And by the way, your string solution will most likely crash if `k` reaches `length()-2` because the if-clause will access characters beyond the length of the string.

Comment: @Kolja Yes, i want to do it with char arrays as scanf has problem with string (corrent me if i'm wrong) because my friend told me scanf is faster than cin.

Comment: I don't think that's a good reason to use C functions if you are working with C++. If there really is a speed difference (which is possible), does it really matter if you are working on just a few characters (of user input, which introduces latencies well above what you would measure in CPU cycles, because, well, you are waiting for the user)? Go for `std::cin`. You could even swap it out later and still work with strings most of the time if you really need to. If you still want to use `scanf`, see Wimmel's answer, it does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`memmove`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/) to copy the remainder of the string to the position of the characters to remove. Use `strlen` to determine how much bytes to move. Note you cannot use `strcpy` because the source and destination buffers overlap.

```
if (zuma[k] == zuma[k + 1] && zuma[k] == zuma[k + 2])
{
    int len = strlen(zuma+k+3) + 1; // +1 to copy '\0' too
    memmove(zuma+k, zuma+k+3, len);
    k = 0;
}
```